# Bug in Laravel? Getting id of record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This seems like a bug, but I am not sure. It's pretty simple.
I have an Installer which belongs to a User. They both have a column named "id" in their table.

```
class Installer extends \Eloquent
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User')->withTrashed();
    }
}
```

In the database, if I run the query below, I get the correct answer, which is installer_id = 97 and user_id = 251

```
SELECT
   installer.id AS 'installer_id',
   user.id AS 'user_id'
 FROM installer
   LEFT JOIN user ON (installer.user_id = user.id)
 WHERE
   installer.installer_id = 'I073102'
;
```

However, in Laravel Eloquent, I get both of them to be 251.

```
$query = Installer::orderBy('user.updated_at', 'DESC')
        ->leftJoin('user', 'user.id', '=', 'installer.user_id')
        ->where('installer_id', '=', $installer_id)
        ->withTrashed()
;

if (Input::has('first_name'))
{
    $query->where('user.first_name', 'LIKE', '%' .  Input::get('first_name') . '%');
}
$installers = $query->paginate(15);
```

And this is the response that I get:

```
$installer->id = 251
$installer->user->id = 251
```

Comment: have you checked the generated sql for that query you are building ?

Comment: This is what I get:

    select * from `installer` left join `user` on `user`.`id` =     `installer`.`user_id` where `installer_id` = ? order by `user`.`updated_at` desc limit 15 offset 0